# How can I force a c++ class method to accept only a handful of integer literals?

Tags: c++, templates, standards

There is a class I'm refactoring which currently has a method:

```
void resize(size_t sz)
```

In the current codebase, sz is always 0,1,2,or 3.
The underlying class is changing from dynamic allocation to a preallocated array of maxsize==3.

How can I get a build time error if someone tries to resize to sz>3 ?
It is easy enough to add a runtime check.  But I'd rather get a compile-time check that fails sooner.

I don't want to change any existing code that makes calls with an integer literal that is in-bounds ,e.g.:

```
x.resize(2)
```

should still compile as is.

But if someone comes along and tries to

```
x.resize(4)
  or
x.resize(n)
```

it should fail to compile or link.

I was thinking about a template specialized on int that is undefined for anything other than {0,1,2,3}. But I'm not sure quite how to make it do what I want within the confines of standard c++.

edit:

I should elaborate on my thoughts of using the template. I am quite willing to change the declaration of the resize function. I am not willing to change the calling code.

e.g.  I was thinking something like

```
void resize( ConstructedFromLiteral<0,3> sz)
```

or

```
void resize( ConstructedFromLiteral<0> sz)
void resize( ConstructedFromLiteral<1> sz)
void resize( ConstructedFromLiteral<2> sz)
void resize( ConstructedFromLiteral<3> sz)
```

Comment: There really isn't any way to do this, especially the part about only being able to call it with an integer literal. You probably just have to give in and rely on convention (i.e., tell people not to call the code with a value outside of the range) backed by runtime assertions.

Comment: The edit just pushes the problem from `resize` to the constructor of `ConstructedFromLiteral`, how to make it compile only for a certain literal or constant value. I just checked gcc to see if it has a warning for converting a an integer constant expression to an enum type that it's out of range for, but it doesn't seem to. Shame.

Comment: @Steve, the edit is to respond to comments that seemed to think the resize method had to stay stagnant.  Also: gcc with -Wall warns on any conversion from int to enum type, not just out of range.

Comment: @Mark: Ah, yes, there's no implicit conversion in C++, I was thinking of C. So even if there was a warning, it wouldn't help. Oops.

Comment: I think the impossibility of your suggestion can be summarized by the observation that you cannot overload functions on values, but only on *types*. Since you want to match `resize(n)`, the only way to extract information about `n` is by overload resolution, but there's no way you can extract the *value* of `n`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way you can get a *compile-time* check for a *run-time value*. Imagine if you said,

```
resize(read_some_number_from_disk());
```

How is the compiler supposed to check that?

However, you *can* make the function a template, since template parameters *are* known at compile time:

```
class Foo
{
  template <unsigned int N> void resize()
  {
    static_assert(N < 4, "Error!");
    //...
  }

  //...

};
```

If you don't have static asserts, you can rig up your own static-assert class that'll fail to compile:

```
template <bool> struct ecstatic_assert;  // no definition!
template <> struct ecstatic_assert<true> { } ;
```

Usage:

```
... resize ... { ecstatic_assert<N < 4> ignore_me; /* ... */ }
```

Comment: The OP says that `x.resize(2) should still compile as is.`

Comment: @K-ballo: OK, let me address that. Thanks.

Comment: wrong. reread question. resize should still accept one argument. but I want to force that argument to be a int literal

Comment: @Mark: I addressed that in the new opening sentence. Please let me know if you have further questions. By the way, you can never distinguish between a literal and, say, a static constant. The language is about *values*, not about representations.

Comment: @Mark: OK, you *could* (but please don't!) make a very crude hack: `#define resize(n) resize_impl<n>()`. Don't use this :-)

Comment: Edited version now correct, but still doesn't provide a way to do what I want.  I'm not ready to accept "you can't do it" yet.  I don't really care whether it is a literal or a static constant. Any value known at compile-time should give me a way to check.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: C++11 constexpr actually would allow this kind of thing to be a compile time check when called with constexpr values, or a  runtime exception if not.

Comment: @MarkBorgerding: Problem is, the function _can't_ know that the value is known at compile time.  You'd have to do the check in the _calling_ function (which knows the value at compile-time) or wrap it in a macro.

Comment: @K-ballo: can you elaborate how you would use `constexpr`? I don't think that's how it works, but I may well be misunderstanding it, so please to add that to your answer.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: There is a nice article on it somewhere, but I cannot find it right now. The basic idea would be in the lines of `constexpr int f( int v ){ return v < 4 ? v : throw std::exception(); }`

Comment: @K-ballo: That's a runtime check, even with constant values.  It'd just get inlined, not compiler errors.

Comment: @K-ballo: That still needs explanation. As far as I understand, `constexpr` only makes a function *eligible* for being a constant expression, *provided* that its arguments are, too. I don't see (nor could I make it work) how your construction can provoke a compile-time error.

Comment: @KerrekSB - that would be a compile time error because `throw` can't appear in a `constexpr` statement IIRC.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I didn't mentioned that as an answer to the OP question, since that would require making reserve a constexpr as well. awoodland is right, if the function is evaluated with constexpr arguments there is a compile time error because of the throw.

Comment: @K-ballo - the problem is making sure it *can't* fall back to become a "normal" function call. The only way I can think to do that is via a template.

Comment: @awoodland: ...or an array size, or an enum value.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `static_assert` to check this at compile time:

```
struct foo {
  template <int N> 
  void resize() {
    static_assert(N >= 0 && N < 4);
  }
};
```

You get `static_assert` builtin in C++11, but it's [easy enough to implement in C++03](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) too. Compared to specialisations it saves you from some quite tedious code duplication.

Comment: wrong. reread question. resize should still accept one argument. but I want to force that argument to be a int literal

Comment: You can't do that. The best you can do is implement it like this and mark the old version as deprecated. You can ease the maintainance pain by making the old version use the newer version internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. You can't keep function calls to resize as is, and check `n` at compile time since its a runtime value. You will need to refactor your code in order to get a compile time error (for instance std/boost static_assert).

Answer (score 0):

You could make four public inlined specialized templates for ints {0, 1, 2, 3}.  These would be simple one-line functions that call a private normal, generic function for any int.

**EDIT:** For the naysayers who say it can't be done using specialized templates (why the downvotes?):

```
class Demo {
private:
    template<int MyInt>
    void PrivateFunction() {
        cout << MyInt << endl;
    }
public:
    template<int MyInt> void PublicFunction();
    template<> void PublicFunction<0>() { PrivateFunction<0>(); }
    template<> void PublicFunction<1>() { PrivateFunction<1>(); }
    template<> void PublicFunction<2>() { PrivateFunction<2>(); }
    template<> void PublicFunction<3>() { PrivateFunction<3>(); }
};
```

Try calling Demo::PublicFunction<4>() and you'll get a linker error.  Accomplishes the same thing and useful if you don't have / don't want to make a static_assert.

As others mentioned, not so easy to check the value of a parameter...

Comment: You can't specialize a function template.

Comment: wrong. reread question. resize should still accept one argument. but I want to force that argument to be a int literal

Comment: My bad, you can't _partially_ specialize.  This is full specialization, so not a problem.

Comment: You totally missed the point.  Callers of resize should not change their code as long as they are calling with a compliant constant value.

Comment: @MarkBorgerding: Again, we _didn't_ miss the point.  What you want can't be done.  This is the easiest/safest workaround.

Answer (score -1):

I don't like this answer for hopefully obvious reasons, but it does satisfy your stated requirements:

```
struct x {
  void true_resize(int n) { }
  template <int N> void template_resize();
};
  template<> void x::template_resize<0>() { true_resize(0); }
  template<> void x::template_resize<1>() { true_resize(1); }
  template<> void x::template_resize<2>() { true_resize(2); }
  template<> void x::template_resize<3>() { true_resize(3); }
#define resize(x) template_resize<x>();


int main () {
  x x;
  x.resize(2);
  x.resize(4);
}
```

In case it isn't obvious, the `#define` doesn't obey C++ scope rules, and so ruins the name `resize` for all other uses.